# Lua C Api Metatables: return conventions for __newindex

Tags: lua

I am implementing a metatable in C with Lua's C API. I wonder whether the `__newindex` method should report success or failure by returning a value, or if this should be handled by using errors.

It seems that in the context of `__index` with `return 0` indicates a failure to look up a value, I wonder whether there is a similar construct in `__newindex`  that avoids ignoring or manual error throwing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua expects no return value from a `newindex` metamethod. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4.

If your failure is fatal, just raise an error inside your metamethod.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a value from C to Lua indicates the number of results pushed onto the stack.  When returning `0` any assignment made in Lua using the result of the method will be `nil`.  When you return `0` in the context of `__index` you are simply indicating that no value has been pushed onto the stack.  You could get the same result by pushing `nil` and returning `1`.

Similarly in the context of `__newindex` your return value from C indicates how many results you have pushed onto the stack.